# Modifying static variable from children widgets in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, widget

Is there a way to share a variable with all your children? and modify it from there?

Hi I am having  an issue in my Flutter App. I want to create a global variable that I send to my model as a parameter in al of the instances of my object like so:

```
  static double totalAmount = 0;
  Beer beer025 = new Beer(0.25, 0, 1, "025", totalAmount);
  Beer beer033 = new Beer(0.33, 0, 1, "033", totalAmount);
  Beer beer050 = new Beer(0.50, 0, 1, "050", totalAmount);
  Beer beer100 = new Beer(1.00, 0, 1, "100", totalAmount);
```

Each object is supossed to add to the `totalAmount` variable the amount in the first parameter of my constructor. (0.25, 0.50...).

And I added this static variable as part of my UI to keep track of how much is the total:

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
  child: Text(
    "$totalAmount",
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 40,
      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Note: When I modify the value directly in the code I have to Restart the entire app to show me the change.

Whatever, qhen I go to my model I have a method that updates the amount of the object itself and it should alsmo update the value of totalAmount but it dosen't, instead aparently it creates a totalAmount for each object instead of using the static one for all of them.

Code:

```
class Beer {
  double cuantity;
  int amount;
  double price;
  String image;
  double totalAmount;

  Beer(this.cuantity, this.amount, this.price, this.image, this.totalAmount);

  //////////////////////////////////////
  // Add and remove beer from the amount
  addBeerAmount(int amountToAdd) {
    this.amount += amountToAdd;
    // Here we update it
    this.totalAmount += this.cuantity * amountToAdd;
    print("Adding to beer " +
        this.cuantity.toString() +
        " // " +
        amountToAdd.toString());
    print("Total:" + this.totalAmount.toString());
  }
```

Output:

```
I/flutter ( 3457): Adding to beer 0.25 // 1
I/flutter ( 3457): Total:0.25
I/flutter ( 3457): Adding to beer 0.25 // 1
I/flutter ( 3457): Total:0.5
I/flutter ( 3457): Adding to beer 0.33 // 1
I/flutter ( 3457): Total:0.33
I/flutter ( 3457): Adding to beer 0.33 // 1
I/flutter ( 3457): Total:0.66
I/flutter ( 3457): Adding to beer 0.5 // 1
I/flutter ( 3457): Total:0.5
I/flutter ( 3457): Adding to beer 0.5 // 1
I/flutter ( 3457): Total:1.0
I/flutter ( 3457): Adding to beer 1.0 // 1
I/flutter ( 3457): Total:1.0
I/flutter ( 3457): Adding to beer 1.0 // 1
I/flutter ( 3457): Total:2.0
```

Here is how pass it to my BeerTitle widget where the UI is ready(The problem is in the parent widget, the one that has to show the changes of the static variable afected by all the children, not in this one):

```
BeerTile(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  beer: beer025,
),
BeerTile(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  beer: beer033,
),
BeerTile(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  beer: beer050,
),
BeerTile(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  beer: beer100,
),
```

No, removing the UniqueKey(didn't work). If you need more details tell me.

[totalAmount is the number at the bottom and I want change it by adding beers with the lateral buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGThO.png)

Comment: look for provider or getX library at https://pub.dev

Comment: No it isn't and for good reason. Maybe you can describe what you want to achieve in plain English with your app and we can suggest an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are handling two different problems: 1) update your state to update the screen values and 2) update your variable.

The problem here `Beer beer025 = new Beer(0.25, 0, 1, "025", totalAmount);` is that you are passing the totalAmount as a `value` and you should be passing a `reference`. A simple way to solve the problem is  changing it to a Map:

```
Map<String, int> totalAmount = {'value': 0};

// inside your beer instance do:
totalAmount['value'] += amountToAdd;
```

For the second problem of updating the screen values, you need to call the function which will update the value of the amount from inside of a setState in your UI or using some sort of state manager like Provider: 
 https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple